# Dozer - Excluding nested Objects

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

According to this example you can do Deep Mapping with Dozer :

http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/deepmapping.html

> ```
> <mapping>
>    <class-a>com.github.dozermapper.core.vo.deep.SrcDeepObj</class-a>
>    <class-b>com.github.dozermapper.core.vo.deep.DestDeepObj</class-b>
>    <field>
>        <a>srcNestedObj.src1</a>
>        <b>dest1</b>
>    </field>
>    <field>
>        <a>srcNestedObj.src2</a>
>        <b>dest2</b>
>    </field>
>    <field>
>        <a>srcNestedObj.srcNestedObj2.src5</a>
>        <b>dest5</b>
>    </field>
> </mapping>
> ```

Similarly I want to exclude few nested objects and fields, and so I tried same way :

> ```
> <mapping map-id="case1" map-null="false">
>    <class-a>com.server.dal.entities.ClassA</class-a>
>    <class-b>com.server.dal.dto.ClassB</class-b>
>
>    <field-exclude>
>        <a>childObj1.childObj2</a>
>        <b>childObj1.childObj2</b>
>    </field-exclude>
>    <field-exclude>
>        <a>childObj1.childObj3.testMap</a>
>        <b>childObj1.childObj3.testMap</b>
>    </field-exclude>
>  </mapping>
> ```

But this is not working as expected. Is there any other way how to exclude nested Object's fields?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can exclude nested objects as follows :

> ```
> <mapping map-id="caseClassA" map-null="false">
>     <class-a>com.server.dal.entities.ClassA</class-a>
>     <class-b>com.server.dal.dto.ClassB</class-b>
>     <field map-id="excludeSubItem1">
>         <a>childObj1</a>
>         <b>childObj1</b>
>     </field>
> </mapping>
> ```

> ```
> <mapping map-id="excludeSubitem1" map-null="false">
>     <class-a>com.server.dal.entities.ClassChild1</class-a>
>     <class-b>com.server.dal.dto.ClassChild1</class-b>
>     <field-exclude>
>         <a>childObj2</a>
>         <b>childObj2</b>
>     </field-exclude>
>     <field map-id="excludeSubItem2">
>         <a>childObj3</a>
>         <b>childObj3</b>
>     </field>
> </mapping>
> ```

> ```
> <mapping map-id="excludeSubitem2" map-null="false">
>     <class-a>com.server.dal.entities.ClassChild3</class-a>
>     <class-b>com.server.dal.dto.ClassChild3</class-b>
>     <field-exclude>
>         <a>testMap</a>
>         <b>testMap</b>
>     </field-exclude>
> </mapping>
> ```